# Get git stash parent commit

Tags: git, git-stash

Is there a way to retrieve the commit from which a stash was originally created?

When creating a stash with the default command `git stash` the original commit is saved in the stash message, so it usually looks like:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on master: abc123 This is the message of some commit.
```

However, if `git stash save 'a stash message'` is used, the commit does not appear in the stash list:

```
stash@{1}: On master: my own message
```

So how could it be retrieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say

```
git log -1 commitish^
```

E.g.

```
git log -1 stash@{0}^
```

Otherwise,

```
git log -g --no-walk --parents refs/stash
```

Comment: Ah, never though of `stash@{X}` as a reference. Works perfectly!

Comment: @LopSae It's not a reference, though, `refs/stash`, is. As you can see, stashes are saved on a "fake branch refs/stash" and the individual items are available as items in the reflog of that fake branch.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Would you mind seeing if you can clarify on my similar question here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62867041/470749