# How can I discover the git commit hash that I stashed from?

Tags: git

I realize that my question is very similar to [How to list the parent commit of a stash in `git stash list`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28590735/470749) and [Get git stash parent commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071720/get-git-stash-parent-commit), but those had so many confusing, disparate responses that I'm asking my own question.

Let's assume that if I run `git stash list`, I see `stash@{0}: On featureX: someMessageHere`

**How can I reveal the hash of the commit that I was working from when I made that stash (which I guess could be considered a parent commit)?**

I've seen so many different answers, and I'm confused about what these each do, how they are different, and which one is the answer to my question:

- `git show stash@{1}^`
- `git log -1 commitish^`
- `git log -1 stash@{0}^`
- `git log -g --no-walk --parents refs/stash`
- `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' --points-at $(git rev-parse refs/stash~1) refs/heads`

```
git log -g --format="%gd %H" refs/stash |
while read name hash; do
    printf "%s %s " $name $(git rev-parse --short $name^)
    git log -1 --format=%s $hash
done
```

<sub>For extra context, [this is the reason I'm asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840077/how-to-recover-from-git-added-by-us-conflict-after-applying-stash-after-renami/62842712#comment111147132_62842712).</sub>

Comment: You could try: `git stash list` I see the commit hash in the output. If there's more than one stash, it would probably be a little trickier.

Comment: To see just the commit hashes use: `git stash list --format='%h'` The command uses the same formatting as `git log`.

Comment: @ColeTierney Thanks for `git stash list --format='%h'`. I think `git stash list` shows different information when the way I called stash was `git stash save -u "someNoteHere"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commit you are looking for is `stash@{0}^` :

```
git show stash@{0}^
git log -1 --oneline stash@{0}^
git rev-parse stash@{0}^
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you for your answer and for your comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840077/how-to-recover-from-git-added-by-us-conflict-after-applying-stash-after-renami/62842712?noredirect=1#comment111172591_62842712

Answer (score 9):

[LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867395/1256452) is correct.  To (I hope) help you understand this part, though:

> I'm confused about what these each do, how they are different, and which one is the answer to my question: [list of various commands]

... let's take a quick (well... maybe not so quick) trip through how Git works internally, in this respect.

First, the big central thing in Git is the *commit*.  There's a recurring theme in Git: you make a commit (`git commit`), you find a commit (many ways), you show a commit (`git show` or sometimes `git log`), you check out a commit (`git checkout` or `git switch`), and you look through or at commits (`git log` again).  Even `git stash` works by making commits.

There are three big features about commits:

- Each one has a unique ID.  This is its *hash ID*, which looks like, e.g., `4a0fcf9f760c9774be77f51e1e88a7499b53d2e2`.  Lots of Git commands abbreviate these—you can sometimes go as short as the first four characters, `4a0f` for instance, as long as that isn't ambiguous, but in a big repository you'll usually need 7 or more characters (and the Linux repository is up to 12 now).<sup>1</sup>
- Each one stores a full snapshot of files.  We won't go into much detail here.
- And, each one stores some *metadata:* information such as who made the commit, when, and why (the log message).  One piece of this metadata is for Git itself, and it gives the hash ID of the commit's *parent* commit—the commit that comes right before the commit itself.

Most commits have exactly one parent.  Some have two or more, in which case the *first* parent is the interesting one here.  At least one commit—the very first one anyone ever made in the repository—necessarily has *no* parent, because there's no commit that comes before the first commit.  Typically there is only one of these *root* commits; all others have history.

---

<sup>1</sup>These things look random, but really are not random at all.  As you add more and more objects to a Git repository, each of which gets one of these unique-to-that-object IDs, it becomes more and more likely that you need to use a more-full name to tell them apart.  It's like a party: the name Bruce might be unique if there are only ten people there, but once you're up to 10,000, you probably need at least a last initial too.

There are four kinds of Git objects in a repository, but mostly, we deal with the commit objects, and get to ignore the others.

---

#### The parent trail is how Git works

This parent—or first parent, for merge commits—is how Git works: **backwards**.  We typically start Git at the *last* commit, or more precisely, the last commit in some branch.  Git then does something about that last commit, such as: show us the author's date and name-and-email and log message.  Then, Git uses the parent of that commit to move back one commit.  It shows us the previous commit.  Then Git goes on to the parent's parent—the grandparent of the original commit—and shows us that commit, and then it moves back again.

When there aren't any merges, this forms a nice simple backwards-looking chain of commits.  If we let a single uppercase letter stand in for each commit's hash ID, we can draw this like so:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` is the *last* commit in the chain.  We (somehow) have Git find this commit, and show it.  Then Git finds `G`'s hash ID, as stored inside the metadata for `H`.  Git uses that to look up commit `G`, which it shows us.  Then Git finds `F`'s hash ID inside `G`, and so on.

(Note that we say that commits *point back* to their earlier—parent—commits.  That's why we drew these backwards-pointing arrows.  It's sometimes important to realize that Git can easily go *backwards*, but has a hard time going *forwards*.  Commit `G` points back to earlier `F`, but not forwards to later `H`.  Most of the time, though, we don't really have to care, and it's hard to draw these arrows well, so most of the time, I don't bother.)

This is what `git log` does, for instance.  But how does it find commit `H`?  Well, the easy way is that we tell it `git log master`.  To the above drawing, we can add one more pointer: we have the *name* `master`, pointing to commit `H`, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

If we `git checkout master` and make a *new* commit, Git will add the new commit such that its parent is `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

but then immediately *update the name `master`* so that it points to commit `I` now:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

What this last part means is that `git log` uses a *name* to find the *last* commit.  If we give it a branch name, that's the name it uses.  If we don't give it any name, `git log` uses the special name `HEAD`.  But we can also give it something that *isn't* a branch name, and that's what `stash` is.

#### What to know about stash commits

When `git stash save` (the old way to make a stash) or `git stash push` (the new way to make a stash) makes its commits, it sets them up so that the special name `stash` refers to one of these commits, *and* that commit has, as its first parent—we'll talk more about *first* parents in a moment—the commit that was (and still is) current right as you run `git stash`.

That is, if we draw them, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
        |\
        i-w   <-- stash
```

I won't go into why I call them `i` and `w` here, but the `git stash` documentation also calls them `I` and `W` (uppercase instead of lowercase—I like to keep my uppercase letters for more normal commits, not for these stash ones).

The important thing here is that the *first parent* of commit `w` is commit `H`, which is the commit you're on at the time you run `git stash push` or whatever you used to create `w`.

#### There's a whole complicated set of ways to name commits

When Git needs a commit—or in fact any internal object, but again we're interested just in the commits here—there are in fact many ways to name it  The complete list is covered in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  For our purposes, though, we want to look specifically at the `^` and `~` suffixes.  We'll get to the curly-brace-and-number suffix later.

If we take some valid name, like `HEAD` or `master` or `stash`, and add a caret / hat `^` or tilde `~` to the end, this is a directive to Git's internal revision-finder: *starting with the commit we've already named, find the commit's parent(s)*.  The `^` suffix then selects the first parent of the commit, so that `stash^` means *the first parent of the commit found by the name `stash`*.

The tilde suffix also selects first-parents.  This seems redundant at first: `develop^` and `develop~` both select the first parent of the commit selected by the name `branch`.  We can add *numbers* after them, though, and then they become different.  The key to understanding this lies in the diagrams we drew above.  Suppose we have:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- develop
         \    /
          K--L   <-- feature
```

Here, commit `M` is a *merge commit*, so it has two parents.  Let's say that the *first* parent of `M` is `J`, and the *second* parent of `M` is `L`—which is what we'd get if we made commit `M` by doing `git checkout develop` when `develop` named commit `J`, then ran `git merge feature` to make `M`.

The syntax `develop^2` means *find the second parent of commit `M`*, i.e., find commit `L`.  This names the same commit that we'd get using the name `feature`—so we could just do that, as long as we haven't yet *deleted* the name `feature`.  But the point is, `M^2` or `develop^2` finds commit `L`, because this means *find the second parent*.

Meanwhile, the syntax `develop~2` means *find the first parent of the first parent of commit `M`*, i.e., find commit `I`.  That's because the `2` in this case is the number times to *step back*.  So we step back once, along the first-parent line from `M` to `J`, then again, along the first (and only) parent line from `J` to `I`.

When the number after `^` or `~` is `1`, or isn't there at all, both do exactly the same thing: `^1` means *find the first parent* (which steps back one first-parent link), and `~1` means *step back one first-parent link*.

#### With that out of the way, let's start looking at your bullet list

> - `git show stash@{1}^`

We'll cover the `@{1}` in a moment.  For now, imagine this just said `stash^`.  The name `stash` would find some commit, and the `^` would find its first parent.  Then `git show` would *show* that commit.  The `git show` command does this by:

- printing out the commit's hash ID
- printing a formatted version of the log message with author and such (you can change this with the `--pretty=format:...` option)
- showing a diff:

  - Git gets this commit's parent's snapshot out, into a temporary area (in memory)
  - then Git gets this commit's snapshot out too
  - and then Git compares the two snapshots and tells you about files that are *different*, without saying anything about files that are the same

The last part makes it look like the commit itself holds a diff—but it doesn't.  The diff was computed for you, when `git show` got around to doing that.

> - `git log -1 commitish^`

Again, the `^` suffix makes Git go back to the commit's parent.  Then `git log -1` shows the log message, but not the diff, of one commit—the first part of what `git show` shows—but with the `-1`, stops after showing that one commit.

> - `git log -1 stash@{0}^`

This is similar, except now we have `stash@{0}^` instead of `commitish^`.  The `^` suffix applies to the `stash@{0}` specifier, which we'll get to in a bit, again.

> - `git log -g --no-walk --parents refs/stash`

This one is quite a bit different.  The `--no-walk` option is redundant with `-g` and has no meaning because `-g` takes over.  The `--parents` option does have a meaning, though.  To talk about `-g` properly, we need to get to the section where we cover the `@{number}` part.  Let's leave the last two commands for later, and get to reflogs now.

#### Reflogs

In Git, each reference—each name like `master` or `develop` or, indeed, `stash`—can also keep its own separate log of "previous" values.  For normal branch names, these logs just remember where the branch names used to point.  Each log entry therefore remembers one hash ID: the *old* value of the branch name.

For instance, when you make a new commit, Git automatically advances the branch name to point to the new commit.  But the name *used* to point to the commit's parent, so the log now contains the parent hash ID.  If you use `git reset` to *re-set* the branch, this puts the pre-reset hash ID into the log, too.  So the log just accumulates each hash ID as you work.

There's one other important thing to know here: the suffix `@{number}` selects the *number*'th log entry.  The number zero means *the current value of the name*.  So `master@{0}` is just a long way to spell `master`, but `master@{1}` is the *old* value of `master`, and `master@{2}` is the value that was the old value, but now is even-older, after you did something that updated `master`.

Git normally purges old log entries after a while—after 90 days by default for most log entries, and 30 days by default for some.  But `stash` is special, and its log entries are normally *never* purged based on age.  Since `stash` isn't a *branch* name, it's not manipulated by branch commands.  It's manipulated instead by the `git stash` command, with its `push`, `pop`, and `drop` operations.

Here, `git stash` uses the `stash` reflog to keep track of earlier saved stashes.  As you use `git stash push`, Git renumbers the previous log entries so that what *was* `stash@{0}` becomes `stash@{1}`, what was `stash@{1}` becomes `stash@{2}`, and so on.  This is actually the same as any normal branch reflog entry (except for the never-expiring part).  But what's different is that when you use `git stash pop` or `git stash drop`, Git will *throw out* the old `stash@{0}` entry, so that what was `stash@{1}` is now `stash@{0}`, what was `stash@{2}` is now `stash@{1}`, and so on.

So now we can properly address the original `stash@{1}^` from the first `git show`:

> `git show stash@{1}^`

The `stash@{1}` operation means *find the stash commit that's one level deep in the stash stack*.  The `^` suffix then selects its first parent.

Since `stash@{1}` is the `w` commit of the stash one level deep in the stash stack, `stash@{1}^` is its parent commit.  That's the commit that this stash is hung from.

We can also, finally, address this one:

> - `git log -g --parents refs/stash`

(I've taken out the pointless `--no-walk`.)

- The `-g` option directs `git log` to look into the reflogs, rather than doing its usual thing of finding a commit and then walking backwards through history.  The one reflog it will look into is that for `refs/stash`—which is the full spelling of `stash`.
- The `--parents` option tells `git log` to show not only each commit hash ID, but also all of its parent commit hash IDs.
- So we'll see each `w` commit in the stash stack, along with *both* of its parents.  The first parent will be the commit from which the `i-w` pair hangs, and the second parent will be the `i` commit.

#### The last two commands

> - `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' --points-at $(git rev-parse refs/stash~1) refs/heads`

The `git for-each-ref` command is an internal workhorse command—one that's not really intended for end users—that implements both `git branch --list` and `git tag --list`, along with several others.  Because this command is meant for writing user-facing commands, rather than being used directly by users, it has a lot of options:

- The `--format` option tells it how to produce its output.  Here, we choose to print the short form of a name (which will be a branch name due to a later option).
- The `--points-at` option tells it not to bother printing the name *unless* the name specifically names a particular commit.  The commit we're telling it we want here is the output of another Git command, `git rev-parse`.
- The `refs/heads` option tells `git for-each-ref` which refs to use.  The `refs/heads` space holds all your branch names.  So this tells it: *Looking only at my branch names, find those that name one specific commit; then, for any name you found, print the short version of that branch's name.*

The commit we choose to have it search for is the hash ID of commit `refs/stash~1`.  This uses the `~` suffix to get the first parent of the commit identified by the name `refs/stash`.  That's the fully-spelled-out form of `stash`, so we're asking Git to use `refs/stash` to find a `w` commit, then using `~` to find its parent, which would be, e.g., commit `H`.  Then we have Git search through all the branch names to see if any of those names commit `H`.  If the name `refs/heads/master`—branch `master`—identifies commit `H`, the command will print the name `master`.

Finally:

> ```
> git log -g --format="%gd %H" refs/stash |
> while read name hash; do
>     printf "%s %s " $name $(git rev-parse --short $name^)
>     git log -1 --format=%s $hash
> done
> ```

This once again uses `git log -g` and `refs/stash` to look at the reflog entries for `refs/stash`.  The `%gd %H` directives to `--format` tell Git *how* to print each such entry: `%gd` prints `stash@{0}` or `stash@{1}` or `stash@{2}` or whatever is appropriate, and `%H` prints the hash ID associated with that reflog entry.

The output from this command goes into a shell loop.  This loop reads the name—the `stash@{number}` part—and the hash ID.  Then the `printf` command prints:

- the name;
- a space;
- the short version of the hash found by `git rev-parse` when given the hash ID we just read plus the `^` suffix, i.e., the short version of the hash of the stash's parent commit;
- and one more space, but no newline yet.

Last, this runs `git log -1 --format=%s $hash`, which prints the subject line of the stash itself.

So this will also print the information you want, though—due to the `--short` in the `git rev-parse` command—using an abbreviated form for each of your stash's appropriate parent commit hash IDs.

Comment: This answer is phenomenal!! Thank you! And I hadn't heard of `git stash push` so will be sure to look that up. And I'm sure I'll keep coming back to this answer to refer to everything you're teaching. Thanks. :-)